pacman update fails because of a ghost cache file
I ran paru -Syu, then sudo pacman -Syu several times with the same outcome.
I get this error:
Total Installed Size:  3034.55 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        49.01 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(222/222) checking keys in keyring           [------------------------------] 100%
(222/222) checking package integrity         [------------------------------] 100%
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/plasma5-themes-sweet-full-git-r390.48a9050-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (checksum)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] 
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

When offered to delete the file, I answer 'Yes', and then the failure message occurs.
I ran sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys successfully, then, sudo pacman -Syyu, but got the same result.
When cd-ing into /var/cache/pacman/pkg/, I found a few plasma5-themes-sweet-full-git-r3* as expected but the latest was r389, no traces of r390, no partial downloads, nothing.
Out of frustration I ran sudo rm on all those files, they are deleted, did not fix anything though. That was a bit dumb, but I do not think it is harmful.
I do not really know how to deal with the fact that it is complaining about a file that is not there, maybe some cache to reset...
Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

See: SOLVED - Question about cleaning the package cache. Does this help?

Thank you, but removing the whole cache and running sudo pacman -Syyu does not fix the problem.


it is complaining about a file that is not there

It seems that it is not there because you answered Yes to delete it. That is, pacman has downloaded the package from a mirror, failed to verify it, and deleted it after the confirmation prompt. The next time you run it, it downloads the same broken file again and fails to verify it again.
Switch to a different mirror in your /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist and try again.

Your explanation is so simple yet logical that I feel pretty dumb now, thanks a lot (just kidding of course). I followed your advice, and was able to updgrade my system. Thank you for the tip about refreshing my mirrors because I would not have thought of it as being the reason behind the 'corrupt file' error message.
